# C language, Hangman game, if question, "char" and "char*" operand issue when comparing answer(the user input) == word(hangman word)

Tags: c, char

I am making a hangman game and have gotten stuck at the point where the code will detect the given value via scanf and check if it's equal to the hangman word.

```
if (answer == word[x])
```

But I keep getting this error

> operand types are incompatible ("char" and "char*")

Any solutions to bypass it?

[Edited]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    //randomwordgenerator
    char word[ARRAY_SIZE][200] = { "tiger", "lion", "hamster", "zebra", "horse", "camel", "lamb", "borne", "eating", "cat" };
    int x = 0;
    char mask[200];

    srand(time(0));

    x = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;

    system("pause");//will pause the rand function

    //printf("%s\n", word[x]);

    //masking and unmasking word
    char m = strlen(word[x]);//will count the number of letters of the random word
    strcpy_s(mask, m, word[x]);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) //loop until all letters are masked
    {
       mask[i] = '_';
       printf("%c ", mask[i]);
    }

    printf("%d\n", x);//only to show what word in the array 0-9

    //Introduction
    printf("\nHey! Can you please save me? \n");
    printf(" O\n/|\\ \n/ \\ \n");

    //Ask for answer
    printf("\nType a letter to guess the word and save me. Here are some tips!\n 1) The '_' above are how many letters make up the word, isn't that neat!\n 2) The letters are case sensitive so please pick lower case or I might die\n 3) Have fun! \nNow with that out of the way please type in your guess; ");
    
    char answer[m];
    char c;

    //loop w counter
    int counter; //for the defeat
    int found = 0; //for the victory
    for (counter = 1; counter < 11; counter++) {
        scanf_s("%s", &c);
        scanf_s("%s", &answer);
        strcpy(answer, &c);

        if (strcmp(answer, word[x]) == 0)
            {
                found++;
            }

        if (found == x)
            {
                printf("\n-------------------------\n");
                printf("           WIN               ");
                printf("\n-------------------------\n");
                break;
            }


        if (counter == 2)
        {
            printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n=========\n");//stand1
        }
        else if (counter == 4)
        {
            printf("\n+\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========\n");//stand2
        }
        else if (counter == 6)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========\n");//stand3 complete
        }
        else if (counter == 8)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|\n|\n|\n=========\n");//head
        }
        else if (counter == 10)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|\n|\n=========\n");//body
        }
        else if (counter == 12)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|    \\ \n|\n=========\n");//right leg
        }
        else if (counter == 14)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|  / \\ \n|\n=========\n");//left leg
        }
        else if (counter == 16)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /| \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========\n");//left hand
        }
        else if (counter == 18)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /|\\ \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========\n");//right hand
        }
        else if (counter == 20)
        {
            printf("\n-------------------------\n");
            printf("          LOSE               ");
            printf("\n-------------------------\n");
            printf("\nReally left me hanging there buddy");//Defeat
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your `answer` is a single character but you are trying to compare to a whole string - that cannot work

Comment: `word[x]` is a "string" - a `char*` in C. You declared your words to be an "array of arrays" or a pointer to a pointer. You can't compare a word against a character. You should loop over the characters of the word to see if they match.

Comment: meaning I should do a word[x]++, so it moves to the next character if answer == word[x]?

Comment: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" means "I understand that the system wants me to add more non-code explanation and presentation of my own thoughts, but I ignore it." It usually is understood as a conscious decision against an honest attempt to ask a question according to [ask]. Making a more [mre] might help by the way.

Comment: Tip: `ARRAY_SIZE` should not be necessary here. C will figure it out for you if you supply a list of values to initialize with. `char *word[]` is a better fit here. If necessary you can compute the array size using `sizeof` and simple math. Conventional C programs usually use a `NULL` terminated array definition, it's just easier to work with.

Comment: `//will pause the rand function` Wat?

Comment: What made you think that adding garbage to your post to get around the *quality* filter would in any way increase the quality of your post? Instead, **read** the tooltips you got and [edit] the post with more information and/or reduce the code to a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you were using the `strcpy_s` function wrong, you didn't give the length of the string. So I changed it like;

```
strcpy_s(mask, m, word[x]);
```

And also, the format specifier we're going to use while getting a string from the user will be `%s` like;

```
scanf_s("%s", &answer);
```

Finally, I prefer using `strcmp` function to compare two strings, if these strings are equal then the result would be `0`, so the `if` statement changes like;

```
if (strcmp(&answer, word[x]) == 0)
```

EDIT: Ok so if you can't use the `if` statement with the input from the user, we can get the input, copy that into another string and then compare these two strings. So I fixed it like;

```
char answer[m];
char c;
//loop w counter
int counter;
for (counter = 1; counter < 11; counter++) {
    scanf_s("%s", &c);
    strcpy(answer, &c);

    if (strcmp(answer, word[x]) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nYou win! The answer was: %s", word[x]);
        return 0;
    }
```

We get an input with `c`, copy the string into an `answer` array, BTW I'm not sure about its size so you can modify it, and then compare these two strings in the `strcmp` function.

EDIT: We don't need another string and copy that into an array, instead, we can directly get the array from the user and just compare it with the `word[x]`. So here's the latest version:

```
char answer[ARRAY_SIZE];
//loop w counter
int counter;
for (counter = 1; counter < 11; counter++) {
    scanf_s("%s", &answer);
    if (strcmp(answer, word[x]) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nYou win! The answer was: %s", word[x]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I get the error `argument of type "char (*)[1]" is incompatible with the parameter of type "constant char *"`. The char (")[1] would be the `char answer[1]` and the constant char * is `word[x]`. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: @Ocelotter is it about the `strcmp` function? It works without any errors in my computer so I can't see it.

Comment: It's the if statment

Comment: @Ocelotter maybe it's because of the arguments of this function, so I edited the answer to make both of the arguments in array type so have a look.

Comment: Hello again, I tried the above and I get the error, `expression must have a constant value` probably due to the rand function, but then that wouldn't make sense as I can print x value and that's the rand value.

Comment: @Ocelotter can you see which line is the error pointing to and what is written in that line?

Comment: It is for the line `char answer[m];`

Comment: try using `char answer[ARRAY_SIZE];` instead, maybe it's because of the `m` value.

Comment: I did just that and it seems to have solved it, but then it asks me to change the `strcpy(answer, &c);` too `strcpy_s(answer, &c);` and when I do that it shows no errors just only 2 warnings. Except when I run the program it says debugging failed, and I get the expression `buffer to small` in the error. When I select to retry, it gives me another warning where the line of code `for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)` gives an exception where the prorgram.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Comment: @Ocelotter so let's get rid of the `strcpy` function, we don't need it at all. If you need to use `strcpy_s`, you need to add a third argument which will be the size of the first array. But we can directly take the first array from the user. Try to use this version, let's see if these errors still occur. I edited the answer and the new version is there.

Comment: I removed the strcpy, and it seems to allow the program to execute and work normally, until when the scanf asks for a value the program just halts. and opens the stdio.h

Comment: @Ocelotter is there an error that the compiler gives or the is the program just ending itself in terminal?

Comment: No erros in the error list, just when I execute it instantly stops and takes me to another page called stdio.h with the following msg `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF318E2079 (ucrtbased.dll) in Hangyman.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000045375F0000.`

Comment: @Ocelotter OK can you try `scanf_s("%s", answer);` without using `&` ?

Comment: @Ocelotter  If that doesn't work either, can you try using `scanf_s("%s", answer, sizeof(answer));` ? This way would be the true usage of `scanf_s`.

Comment: Hello, with the help of a friend we managed to solve the issue. strcpy was indeed a problem and there was a buffer issue but my friend managed to solve it. Thank you again for all your help

Comment: @Ocelotter Great then :)